# SQL subquery returns more then 1 row

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run this query :

```
 select r.rolekey 
 from roles r 
 where r.rolekey in  (select r.rolekey 
                       from roles r 
                      where r.role_name like
                     (concat('%',
                      replace ((
                         select s.rolename 
                         from savroles s 
                          join user_savroles us 
                           on s.rolekey = us.rolekey 
                          where us.userkey = 24),'ROLE_REPONSABLE_RESSOURCE_',''),'%'))) ;
```

Problem : I have table SAV roles where SAV role name is like : ROLE_REPONSABLE_RESSOURCE_SAP_SIAG or ROLE_REPONSABLE_RESSOURCE_SAP_CIIAM. I can assign 1 or many SAV roles to a user.
THen I have a table "roles' where roles name are like : APP_SAP_CIIAM_Z_XX_BASIC,APP_SAP_SIAG_BW_ZU_CT_SIAGBI,ROLE_REPONSABLE_RESSOURCE_SAP_CIIAM. Basically the Roles name contains SAP_SIAG or SAP_CIIAM that is also a string in SAV role.
This query works if user has only 1 SAV role but when I assign more then I get Error code 1242 subquery returns more then 1 row.

I could point to a specific subquery in this query that seems to be a probelm :

select replace ((select s.rolename from savroles s join user_savroles us on s.rolekey = us.rolekey where us.userkey = 24 ),'ROLE_REPONSABLE_RESSOURCE_',''); I think replace does not like more then 1 result.

How I can overcome this issue - I want to build a list of SAV roles on which I run a replace so the list will contain only pure substrings like SAP_SIAG and then I want to concat the string with % so it can be compared to Roles.

Answer (score 0):

`replace` expect single value, not `unbounded`. limit the result of your `subquery`. you use a subquery to join the filter again to your main table

```
select r.rolekey 
from roles r 
inner join 
    (select r.rolekey from roles r 
        inner join savroles s on r.role_name like concat('%', replace(s.rolename, 'ROLE_REPONSABLE_RESSOURCE_',''), '%')
        inner join user_savroles us on s.rolekey = us.rolekey       
        where us.userkey = 24) 
t1 on t1.rolekey = r.rolekey;
```

Comment: HI Both does not solve the problem. What i need to do is to create a list of strings by adjusting any result returned from the "select s.rolename from savroles s join user_savroles us on s.rolekey = us.rolekey where us.userkey = 24", first advice will only limit the search to 1 which works the same as assinging user only 1 SAV role. Second advice is not resulting in what is needed. So lets say I have 2 collumn column A have values of SAV ROLE collumn B have values from ROLES. The values are not the same but contains similar string inside the text itself - like SAP_CIAM. How to return all resul